# No module named django.views

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.5

After many modifications on my Django project, it doesn't work. :

```
ImportError at /

No module named django.views

Request Method: GET

    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000
/
Django Version: 1.5.1

Exception Type: ImportError

Exception Value:

No module named django.views

Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35

Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python

Python Version: 2.7.3

Python Path:

['/home/moi/dev/logistique',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
```

urls.py :

```
#from django.views.generic import ListView

#from django.views.generic import CreateView

from rtag.models import Rtag

from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()



urlpatterns = patterns( 'rtag.views',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^$', 'accueil', name="url_accueil"),

    url(r'^list_by_wo/$', 'orderbywo', name="list_by_wo"),

    url(r'^list_by_sn/$', 'orderbysn', name="list_by_sn"),

    url(r'^list_by_create_date/$', 'orderbycreate_date', name="list_by_create_date"),

    url(r'^list_by_PN/$', 'orderbyPN', name="list_by_PN"),

    url(r'^list_by_return_reason/$', 'orderbyreturn_reason',     name="list_by_return_reason"),

    url(r'^list_by_fault_type/$', 'orderbyfault_type', name="list_by_fault_type"),

    url(r'^list_by_Error_message/$', 'orderbyerrormessage', name="list_by_Error_message"),

    url(r'^list_by_user/$', 'orderbyuser', name="list_by_user"),

    url(r'^list_by_custo/$', 'orderbycusto', name="list_by_custo"),

    url(r'^connexion/$', 'connexion' , name="connexion"),

    url(r'^deconnexion/$', 'deconnexion' , name="deconnexion"),

    url(r'^ajout/$', 'ajout'),

    url(r'^rtag/(?P<Id_rtag>\d+)$', 'details'),

    url(r'^modif/(?P<Id_rtag>\d+)$', 'modif'),

    url(r'^csv/$', 'generate_csv'),

    url(r'^admin/jsi18n', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog'),

)





  #SI EN PRODUCTION MERCI DE COMMENTER LA LIGNE SUIVANTE:

  urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

my settings.py:

```
    # Django settings for logistique project.
  DEBUG = True
  TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

  ADMINS = (
     )

 MANAGERS = ADMINS

 DATABASES = {
      'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
         'NAME': 'logistiquedb',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
          'USER': 'user',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
          'PASSWORD': 'password',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
          'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
          'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
     }
  }

  # Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
  # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/{{ docs_version }}/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
  ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

  # Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
  # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
  # although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
  # On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
  # timezone as the operating system.
  # If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
  # system time zone.
  TIME_ZONE = ''

  # Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
  # http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
  LANGUAGE_CODE = 'En-us'

  SITE_ID = 1

  # If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
  # to load the internationalization machinery.
  USE_I18N = True

  # If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
  # calendars according to the current locale
  USE_L10N = True

  # Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
  # Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
  MEDIA_ROOT = ''

  # URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
  # trailing slash.
  # Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
  MEDIA_URL = ''

  # Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
  # Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
  # in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
  # Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
  STATIC_ROOT = ''

  # URL prefix for static files.
  # Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'

  # URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
  # Make sure to use a trailing slash.
  # Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
  # ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

  # Additional locations of static files
  STATICFILES_DIRS = (
      # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
      # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
      # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
      "/home/moi/dev/static/",
  )

  # List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
  # various locations.
  STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
      'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
      'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
      'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
  )

  # Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
  SECRET_KEY = 'w7)27t-u-^e+ruc6)+n11jm-5e+u%tp44z5wq#%$p(=4+#^8-%'

  # List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
  TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
      'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
      'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
      'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
  )

  MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
      'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  )

  ROOT_URLCONF = 'logistique.urls'

  TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
      # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or             "C:/www/django/templates".
      # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
      # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
      '/home/$USER/logistique/rtag/templates',

  )

  INSTALLED_APPS = (
      'django.contrib.auth',
      'django.contrib.contenttypes',
      'django.contrib.sessions',
      'django.contrib.sites',
      'django.contrib.messages',
      'django.contrib.staticfiles',
      'logistique.systems',
      'logistique.localstocks',
      'logistique.partnumbers',
      'logistique.rtag',
      'django.contrib.admin',
      # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
       'django.contrib.admindocs',
  )

  # A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
  # performed by this configuration is to send an email to
  # the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
  # See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
  LOGIN_URL = '/connexion/'
  # more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
  LOGGING = {
      'version': 1,
      'disable_existing_loggers': False,
      'handlers': {
          'mail_admins': {
              'level': 'ERROR',
              'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
          }
      },
      'loggers': {
          'django.request': {
              'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
              'level': 'ERROR',
              'propagate': True,
          },
      }
  }
```

I have the same error on all my urls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problematic pattern is the last one:

```
url(r'^admin/jsi18n', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog'),
```

because you've added these patterns with the `'rtag.views'` prefix. That means Django is looking for a view importable as `rtag.views.django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog`. You could instead break these up into another set of url patterns

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/jsi18n', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns( 'rtag.views',

    url(r'^$', 'accueil', name="url_accueil"),

    url(r'^list_by_wo/$', 'orderbywo', name="list_by_wo"),

    url(r'^list_by_sn/$', 'orderbysn', name="list_by_sn"),

    url(r'^list_by_create_date/$', 'orderbycreate_date', name="list_by_create_date"),

    url(r'^list_by_PN/$', 'orderbyPN', name="list_by_PN"),

    url(r'^list_by_return_reason/$', 'orderbyreturn_reason',     name="list_by_return_reason"),

    url(r'^list_by_fault_type/$', 'orderbyfault_type', name="list_by_fault_type"),

    url(r'^list_by_Error_message/$', 'orderbyerrormessage', name="list_by_Error_message"),

    url(r'^list_by_user/$', 'orderbyuser', name="list_by_user"),

    url(r'^list_by_custo/$', 'orderbycusto', name="list_by_custo"),

    url(r'^connexion/$', 'connexion' , name="connexion"),

    url(r'^deconnexion/$', 'deconnexion' , name="deconnexion"),

    url(r'^ajout/$', 'ajout'),

    url(r'^rtag/(?P<Id_rtag>\d+)$', 'details'),

    url(r'^modif/(?P<Id_rtag>\d+)$', 'modif'),

    url(r'^csv/$', 'generate_csv'),

)
```

Better yet move all of the `rtag.views` urls to a `rtag.urls` file and include that in the root url conf.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/jsi18n', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog'),
    url(r'^', include('rtag.urls')),
)
```